# Pact flow for Event Driven Applications

Tags: pact, pact-broker

Although Pact supports testing of messages, I find that the recommended flow in the "Pact Nirvana" doesn't quite match the flow that I understand an *Event Driven Application* needs.

Let's say we have an *Order management service* and a *Shipping management service*.
The *Shipping* service emits `ShippingPreparedEvent`s that are received by the *Order* service.

If we deleted a field inside the `ShippingPreparedEvent`, I'd expect first to make a change to the Order service so that it stops reading the old field. Deploy it. And then make the change in the *Shipping* service and deploy it.
That way, there wouldn't have any downtime on the services.

However, I believe Pact would expect to deploy the *Shipping* service first (it's the provider of the event) so that the contract can be verified before deploying the consumer. In this case, deploying the provider first will break my consumer.

Can this situation be avoided somehow? Am I missing anything?

Just to provide more context, we can see in this link that different changes would require different order of deployment. https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#summary
I won't be using Kafka nor Avro, but I believe my flow would be similar.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we deleted a field inside the ShippingPreparedEvent, I'd expect first to make a change to the Order service so that it stops reading the old field. Deploy it. And then make the change in the Shipping service and deploy it. That way, there wouldn't have any downtime on the services.

I agree. What specifically in the Pact Nirvana guide gives you the impression this isn't the way to go? Pact (and the Pact Broker) don't actually care about the order of deployments.

In your case, removing the field would cause a failure of a `can-i-deploy` check, because removing the field would break the `Order Management Service`. The only approach would be to remove the field usage from the consumer, publish a new version of that contract and deploy to Production first.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think about the need of deploying the customer first so that the field is no longer required in the contract. 
Actually, my initial question was a bit different but I tried to find an equivalent situation for StackOverflow and now I realise it's not exactly what I wanted. I might create a follow-up question but I'll mark this one as solved.
Thanks!